# What is the best way to handle response in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I use RestSharp and I want to know what is the best way to handle response. There are `ErrorMessage`, `ErrorException` and `ResponseStatus` in `RestResponse` but how can I check whether request was successful?

I use this code. Does it look ok?

```
if (response.ResponseStatus != ResponseStatus.Completed)
{
    throw new ApplicationException(response.ErrorMessage);
}
```

Comment: This code won't throw an exception if the REST service responds with a non-200s error.  As per https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Getting-Started "If an API returns a 404, ResponseStatus will still be Completed."

Answer (score 9):

This will not always catch all of the errors.  As Jacob said, a `ResponseStatus` can have a value of Completed even if it returns a 404 or some other bad status.

Instead, use `StatusCode` which handles all of the `HttpStatus` responses.

```
if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
  throw new ApplicationException(response.ErrorMessage);
```

Comment: This assumes that the endpoint being called always returns 200, it would need to check for any 2xx response code.

Answer (score -1):

It's correct. you can handle other response type by convention